# WKWebView content rendered off-screen with negative offset, but touch targets rendered correctly

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am attempting to integrate a WKWebView into my app on iOS 11, but I'm running into this issue with any webpage I load

[iphone sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gvBo.png)

the page will visually load slightly off-screen for some reason, but the touch targets for everything are where you would expect them to be:

[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJyW5.png)

I opened up the view debugger and it seems like all the webview's subviews are laid out properly, except for a single view: the subview of the WKContentView has a frame of (x: -187.5 y: -301.5 w: 375 h: 603) while every other subview's frame has an origin of (0,0). I have tried calling setNeedsLayout() on the webview, setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints both on and off, and adding constraints to the edges of the superview and I used apple's boilerplate found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

[xcode view debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHxwc.png)

[weird frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjIcN.png)

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong?